# Forecasting quarterly seasonal time series

Tags: regression, forecasting, seasonality

I have to build a forecasting model to predict one very seasonal time series.

I want to predict it with external variables.

My first approach was to de-seasonalize the data (time series frequency is quarter) and then to perform some kind of regression (mostly linear with some regularization but also tried SVM for regression and GBM without terrific success).

The problem is that I have trouble to de-seasonalize correctly since the seasonal factors are increasing over time. 
Then I tried to build dummies variable that are increasing (some kind of trend dummies (don't know if that exists :) )
Results were not better.

Therefore, I am trying to build one model for each quarter. I have then much less data to learn the model (once a year instead of four) but I am much more confident in this approach.
The problem is that when I predict a quarter I do not take into account the forecasting error I made in the last quarter or all the information I got from the last three quarters. Do you have any idea of what I can do?

I was thinking about Kalman filter but I have never implemented it so I don't know if it could be done in this context ?
If yes, can you give me the main idea?

Comment: You may be interested in the methods and software mentioned in [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144894/what-is-the-best-filter-way-for-deseasonalizing-quarterly-data).

Comment: What is size and sampling frequency of historical data? What is forecast horizon and time-step? Is you process stationary (stable level and variance)?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
@jvalacalle Thanks but actually I have alredy tried some of this methods even though I did not manage to perform x12 because of the complexity of the R package I could not figure out how to make it work.

Comment: @Aksakal Thanks for your answer. I have data from 1990 to 2015 quaterly. And now I am trying to make 4 models. One for each quarter which does not stupid if you look at external variables. The process may respond differently according to the quarter. The process is quite stable in term of level (slight increase but it can be encompass in one of the external variable actually). The variance is increasing (that is why i used increasing dummies).
For the forecast I'd like one year ahead (that is one step if we consider the 4 quarters models)

Comment: A little up !
Anyone ? :)
I have built my four models, they work correctly but I want to make them interactive.
The errors does not seem much correlated between 2 quarters :/
Thanks,

Comment: Post your data to dropbox.com

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Just posted it here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cvntnrkuvprx0bd/data.csv?dl=0
The first column is the variable to explain and next columns are the regressors. I used some variations of them (differences, caped variables, etc..)
The first row is 1981Q1 and then Q2 Q3 and so on...
I do not like to much AR models... and I would like to avoid it as much as possible.
Thanks a lot but I do not want you to waste to much time on it :s

For the moment, I just made 4 models for each quarter. There is no AR so they do not interact at all